# How to wrap a C++ struct in Cython in order to call a C++ constructor?

Tags: c++, struct, cython

I am new to the Cython/C++ interface and currently studying the examples in the documentation. I am trying to find a way to wrap a C++ struct (instead of C/C++ native types) that is used as the type specifier of the argument of a C++ class constructor. Then I can instantiate a C++ class on the Python side.

First, the `rectangle.cpp` file which is a simplified version of the example with only constructors. Here I introduce a struct to be used as the type of the argument for the constructor. (I merged the `.h` header file with `.cpp` just to make the post shorter. This compiles normally,though.)

**rectangle.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace shapes {

    struct Point {
        int x0;
        int y0;
        int x1;
        int y1;
    };

    class Rectangle {
        public:
            int x0, y0, x1, y1;
            Rectangle();
            Rectangle(Point point);
            ~Rectangle();
    };

    // Default constructor
    Rectangle::Rectangle () {}

    Rectangle::Rectangle (Point point) {
        this->x0 = point.x0;
        this->y0 = point.y0;
        this->x1 = point.x1;
        this->y1 = point.y1;
    }

    // Destructor
    Rectangle::~Rectangle () {}
}
```

Second, the `rectangle.pxd` file which is basically a copy from the example, except that I included a `cdef struct Point` to declare the structure. (**Not sure if this is a correct approach.**)

**rectangle.pxd**

```
# Declare the class with cdef
cdef extern from "rectangle.cpp" namespace "shapes":
    cdef struct Point:
        int x0
        int y0
        int x1
        int y1 

    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle() except +
        Rectangle(Point) except + # Not sure if this is correct
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
```

Third, the `rect.pyx` file

**rect.pyx**

```
# distutils: language = c++

from rectangle cimport Rectangle, Point

# Create a Cython extension type which holds a C++ instance
# as an attribute and create a bunch of forwarding methods
# Python extension type.
cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Point point # Not sure if this is correct

    cdef Rectangle c_rect  # Hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping

    def __cinit__(self, Point point):
        self.c_rect = Rectangle(point)
```

Finally, the `setup.py` which is identical to the example.

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("rect.pyx"))
```

If I compile using the standard command `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`, the following error pops out. (The original example can compile and run without any problem.)

```
[1/1] Cythonizing rect.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    PyTypeObject *Py_TYPE(obj)
    bint PyMapping_Check(obj)
    object PyErr_Format(exc, const char *format, ...)

@cname("__pyx_convert__from_py_shapes::Point")
cdef Point __pyx_convert__from_py_shapes::Point(obj) except *:
                                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

FromPyStructUtility:11:41: Expected an identifier or literal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    setup(ext_modules=cythonize("rect.pyx"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 877, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 997, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: rect.pyx
```

I am sure there are mistakes in wrapping the struct, since the error is triggered by `FromPyStructUtility`. But I haven't found a straightforward answer/solution to this particular scenario. If I want to keep the C++ code as it is, i.e., insisting on passing a struct to the constructor, how do I implement this on the Cython side? Your comments/suggestions/tutorials will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you plan to pass Point as argument of a def function (like __init__) you have to wrap it in a PyPoint, the same way you do it for Rectangle.

Comment: @ead Could you please substantiate? Some code example would definitely help.